# yum:How can I instruct yum to install a specific version for X

Tags: yum, rpm

I have to implement two yum repos, **x** and **y** which contains same packages with different versions.

If a user do:

1. `yum install x` - should install the latest packages of one branch
2. `yum install y` - should install the stable version from different branch

When I execute `yum install x`, installs the latest version package from **x** repository, but when I execute, `yum install y`, doesn't work as expected though I have created meta packages.

I have experimented with yum plugins `protect`, `priority`. Both plugins works as expected but removes the other package versions.

I am able to execute `yum install y`, but unable to execute `yum install x` afterwards.

I should be able to execute both repositories in one server.

Could you please suggest me, how to achieve this in yum? I have to implement it in server.

Comment: Sounds a little *broken by design* by the description you provided. Usually this is done by using different package names like `foo-stable` or `foo-latest` or something like that. It would help if you could add some more details regarding the versions of your packages x and y.

Comment: The package name of both repo's same. Like foo is the package. Rpm looks like foo-1.1-buildnum-x86_64.rpm. Buildnum differs. We have cricteria not to modify the package name

Comment: Yep, that is basically broken by design, your problem is not the repo definition but rpm name/epoch/version/release comparison. You can either install a specific version, or install the latest by only using the name, and if you want the "older" version then use `yum downgrade` or `rpm --oldpackage` to downgrade.

What you still could do is to add a `Provides: name-latest` to the package, and `Provides: name-stable` to the one with the lower version number, so you don't have to change the package name but still have a way to select between both packages. You can also use a versioned Provides.

Answer (score 0):

- Check out yum upgrade-to x-version (like x-1.0.1). Maybe that is what you need
- You can use yum --disablerepo in order to use only the relevant repository (latest or stable)

Comment: Is there any other way to implement apart from disablerepo. I cannot inform user to disable repo to install the package.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Lets see what others will answer. upgrade-to won't help?